# Lost frameworks in iOS 4.2

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios-4.2, iphone

I recently updated my iOS SDK to 4.2 and now my frameworks have some wrong file-paths…
I found a lot of these frameworks but I couldn't find the UIKit etc.

But it must be in the same folder, so what should I do?

Can I download these frameworks from somewhere!?

[image: XCode Frameworks]

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, and I discovered that the frameworks aren't actually missing - they have just become unlinked to your project.

To get them back, delete them from your project, and then re-add them - preferably one at a time.

I was able to sometimes reproduce this issue by trying to add (or move) multiple frameworks at a time.  When I worked with them one at a time, it always worked.

Good luck!